# Add an active class on menu item when on the page (Wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress

I believe this question has been asked several (many) times but couldnt figure out how to solve it. 
I'm using the wordpress menu which basically looks like :

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I simply need to add a class when user will be in that page (the same process than stackoverflow and the "youarehere" class on the menu). But I cant manage to do it. thanks

Comment: If you're using a standard WP menu it should have active states.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are talking about, can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the WP Navigation Menus for this, which will create an active state. Add to your functions file:

```
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Then you call it up in your theme:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

WordPress will also generate states for parent/ancestors as so:

```
.current-menu-parent
.current-{object}-parent
.current-{type}-parent

.current-menu-ancestor
.current-{object}-ancestor
.current-{type}-ancestor
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave .current-menu-item the style I wanted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new menu in the Wordpress backend and apply it to the template via `wp nav menu` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) then the 'active' class is applied automatically when you are on that page/post.

You also get parents and ancestors classes for nested menus meaning that you can style active parent links.

Here's the list of CSS classes you can use;

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes